# CSS animate transition when jQuery .html() completes

Tags: jquery, css-transitions, race-condition

What I want to do is to append a container, fill it with content, and then animate it in by removing a class and letting CSS handle it through a transition. I'm able to do all of that except animate it in. I think it might be some kind of race condition or something similar, because if I put a setTimeout() on removing the class, it will animate in. Here's a fiddle with both examples:

http://jsfiddle.net/38q7A/3/

**HTML**

```
<div class="test1">test 1</div>

<div class="container"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.flyin {
     -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
     -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
     transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.left {
     position: fixed;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
 }
```

**JavaScript**

```
function test1(){
     $(".container").append("<div class='flyin left'></div>");
     $(".flyin").html("this is test content");
     $(".flyin").removeClass("left");
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if changing the html is an option, but you could have an empty flying-left element pre-generated and only trigger the animation on click http://jsfiddle.net/uHPmc/1/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left flyin"></div>    
</div>

function test1(){
    $(".flyin").html("this is test content");
    $(".flyin").removeClass("left");
    $(".container").append("<div class='flyin left'></div>");
};
```

Comment: I tried this one too and it worked, but I rather not have html on the page that I don't need right away. Any idea why this works over appending it? I thought append was a synchronous call.

Comment: I think I'm getting closer to finding out what the problem is. It looks like the class "left" that puts the flyin off the page isn't being evaluated before before I remove it. Either that, or the animation isn't. http://jsfiddle.net/38q7A/11/

Comment: I think it's only synchronous in the sense that you can ineract with the object in the dom tree but the rendering only takes place after the event handler, which also makes sense from a performance perspective.

Comment: That makes sense to me. What I ended up doing is checking its position on the screen which causes a reflow (I think). That way the styles are evaluated and I'm able to animate it by removing the class. Of course, it could be doing something completely different, but it is working. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Here's is a link to the solution if you or anyone else who comes across this is interested. 

http://jsfiddle.net/38q7A/12/